# Xcode Having trouble loading a View via code

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am working on an iOS app and am having some difficulties. I am using storyboards and have placed a button which is connected modally to launch another view. The button works great. However, the button is really just a placeholder and in reality, I would like some code to launch the new view. I have tried several methods, all of which seemed straightforward but result in nothing happening. Is there a way to have my code activate the segue that my button currently activates?

Answer (score 1):

I think @ctrahey 's solution should work.  Try dragging the segue from the source view controller (not the button, but the vc that contains it) to the destination view controller and be sure to set it's type to modal.

I think `sender == self` vs. `nil` shouldn't matter in this case.

However, if that doesn't work, my usual practice for modal vcs is to not draw any segues to them in IB.  Instead, I let the modal VC float in IB with no connections, giving it an "Identifier" on the attributes inspector.  Then I use code like this:

```
// be sure to use the real name of your storyboard
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

// use the identifier you assigned to the modal vc
MyModalViewController *newVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyModalViewController"];

// presentingVC might be self, if this code is inside a vc
[presentingVC presentModalViewController:newVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: I'll provide a few more details, maybe that will help explain why these solutions are not working. I am working with GameCenter, and attempting to launch a new view after a game is created between the user and another player. As soon as you click play game, my function to launch the new view is executed (I can confirm this because I have NSLogged it). However, all that happens is the GameCenter view is dismissed (this happens after my other code has already executed and done nothing), revealing my original viewController.

Answer (score 0):

Give your segue an identifier (in the right-hand inspector panel), then in a view controller (from the same storyboard) do:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSeguesIdentifier" sender:self];
```

Comment: The function performSegueWithIdentifier also calls for a sender argument. I have tried passing nil as the second argument. So far there is no visible result on the screen. I have NSLog showing me that the code IS being executed.